# How can I create a widget for context? Null check operator used on a null value(widget)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have encountered a problem. Flutter debugger says, "Null check operator used on a null value", highlighting the code below in framework.dart.

```
      /// The configuration for this element.
      ///
      /// Avoid overriding this field on [Element] subtypes to provide a more
      /// specific widget type (i.e. [StatelessElement] and [StatelessWidget]).
      /// Instead, cast at any callsites where the more specific type is required.
      /// This avoids significant cast overhead on the getter which is accessed
      /// throughout the framework internals during the build phase - and for which
      /// the more specific type information is not used.
          @override
          Widget get widget => _widget!;
```

I found that context in the following code have no widget, but I can't figure out  how to create a widget of context.

```
              id: context.read<SignupCubit>().state.user!.uid,
```

I believe my following codes are completely same as the those published on github.
https://github.com/maxonflutter/flutter_dating_app_series/blob/master/lib/screens/onboarding/widgets/custom_button.dart

```
• Flutter version 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1430 
• Dart version 2.18.0 (build 2.18.0-234.0.dev)
```

```
   import 'package:datingapp/blocs/blocs.dart';
    import 'package:datingapp/cubits/cubit/signup_cubit.dart';
    import 'package:datingapp/model/models.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
    
    class Custombutton extends StatelessWidget {
      final TabController tabController;
      final String text;
      final void function;
    
      const Custombutton(
          {Key? key,
          required this.tabController,
          this.text = 'Start',
          this.function})
          : super(key: key);
    
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor
              ])),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style:
                ElevatedButton.styleFrom(elevation: 0, primary: Colors.transparent),
            onPressed: () async {
              if (tabController.index == 5) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              } else {
                tabController.animateTo(tabController.index + 1);
              }
              if (tabController.index == 2) {
                await context.read<SignupCubit>().signupWithCredentials();
                User user = User(
                  id: context.read<SignupCubit>().state.user!.uid,
                  name: '',
                  age: 0,
                  gender: '',
                  imageUrls: [],
                  interests: [],
                  bio: '',
                  jobTitle: '',
                  location: '',
                  matches: [],
                  swipeLeft: [],
                  swipeRight: [],
                );
                context.read<OnboardingBloc>().add(StartOnbording(user: user));
              }
            },
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .textTheme
                      .headline4!
                      .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import '../../repositories/auth/auth_repository.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;

part 'signup_state.dart';

class SignupCubit extends Cubit<SignupState> {
  final AuthRepository _authRepository;

  SignupCubit({required AuthRepository authRepository})
      : _authRepository = authRepository,
        super(SignupState.initial());

  void emailChanged(String value) {
    emit(state.copywith(email: value, status: SignupStatus.initial));
  }

  void passwordChanged(String value) {
    emit(state.copywith(password: value, status: SignupStatus.initial));
  }

  Future<void> signupWithCredentials() async {
    if (!state.isValid || state.status == SignupStatus.submitting) return;
    emit(state.copywith(status: SignupStatus.submitting));
    try {
      var user = await _authRepository.signUp(
          email: state.email, password: state.password);
      emit(
        state.copywith(
          status: SignupStatus.success,
          user: user,
        ),
      );
    } catch (_) {}
  }
}

part of 'signup_cubit.dart';

enum SignupStatus { initial, submitting, success, error }

class SignupState extends Equatable {
  final String email;
  final String password;
  final SignupStatus status;
  final auth.User? user;

  bool get isValid => email.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty;

  const SignupState(
      {required this.email,
      required this.password,
      required this.status,
      this.user});

  factory SignupState.initial() {
    return SignupState(
        email: '', password: '', status: SignupStatus.initial, user: null);
  }

  @override
  bool get stringify => true;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [email, password, status, user];

  SignupState copywith({
    String? email,
    String? password,
    SignupStatus? status,
    auth.User? user,
  }) {
    return SignupState(
        email: email ?? this.email,
        password: password ?? this.password,
        status: status ?? this.status,
        user: user ?? this.user);
  }
}
```

the followings are dartpackages I use.

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  step_progress_indicator: ^1.0.2
  intl: ^0.17.0
  firebase_core: ^1.17.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.13
  image_picker: ^0.8.5
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.12
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.15
```

Comment: are you latest version of packages?  try upgrading them

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a null check operator (!) in a null variable. It might the `context.read<SignupCubit>().state.user!.uid,`. Make sure it is not null before calling it or just change your null operators to replace if it's null like that:

```
// If user is null, use '' (empty string) instead of null
id: context.read<SignupCubit>().state.user?.uid ?? ''
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but this solution doesn't work for me. The same error happens again.

Comment: So it means that it couldn't find the SignupCubit in your context. I see your update, the context is not a widget. The context (provided as parameter in the build) is the element associated with the widget being built and is certainly not null. Make sure the Provider is above in the tree or, if it is in the same level, user a Builder to create a context one level down.